# OOP basics: How to define a Python class to create an array of object instances?

Tags: python, arrays, oop

I have a set of display boards that I want to treat as a single logical display.
Each display has 4 digits. The [library I'm using](https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/projects/ht16k33/en/latest/) creates an object instance for each display board. Using the library as-is, I end up with three instances for three boards:

```
display0 = segments_gpio.Seg14x8(i2c,0) 
display1 = segments_gpio.Seg14x8(i2c,1) 
display2 = segments_gpio.Seg14x8(i2c,2)
```

To write to these boards I can use code like this:

```
display0[0] = '0'
display0[1] = '1'
display0[3] = '2'
display1[0] = 'A'
display1[1] = 'B'
display1[3] = 'C'
```

This compiles and runs fine, but has obvious limitations. I'm trying to create a multi-display class that will allow me to write code like

```
char = 65 # 'A'
for disp in range(0,3):
    for digit in range(0,4):
        displays[disp][digit] = char
        char += 1
```

Or, even better:

```
char = 65    # sequence from letter 'A'
for digit in range(0,12):
    displays[digit] = char
    char += 1
```

I tried creating the multidisplay class like this:

```
class mdisplay(segments_gpio.Seg14x8(i2c)):
    
    displayset = []
    def __init__():
        for x in range(0,3):
            print ("create display ",x)
            # instantiate display and append to displayset
            displayset.append(segments_gpio.Seg14x8(i2c,x))
```

The intention is to create an array of display objects in displayset.

I instantiated it like this:

```
mydisplays = mdisplay(i2c)
```

And referenced it like this

```
for z in range(0,3):
    mydisplays[z][0] = chr(z+48)
    mydisplays[z][1] = chr(z+65) 
    mydisplays[z][3] = chr(z+97)
```

This is producing errors in the imported libraries that don't occur when I use the non-object approach for accessing the display:

```
    self.disp_d0 = (dispID & 1) != 0
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

I suspect I have declared the class incorrectly, but I'm not sure where.

Edit 2020-09-06 - Moving on with a different approach. I don't really need a new class, but just want to be able to address the multiple displays and digits with variables like a list or array.

I found [this article,](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-list-of-object-in-python-class/) which showed how to create a list of object instances:
Using that as a guide, I have this working code:

```
display = []
display.append(segments_gpio.Seg14x8(i2c,0)) 
display.append(segments_gpio.Seg14x8(i2c,1))
display.append(segments_gpio.Seg14x8(i2c,2))   

charnum = 33
for boardindex in range(0,3):
    display[boardindex].fill(0)
    display[boardindex].brightness = .2
    for digitindex in range(0,8):
            display[boardindex][digitindex] = chr(charnum)
            charnum += 1;
```

From here the next enhancement would be to make the display addressable with a single index representing the digit in the combined display of 3 boards with 8 digits each.

```
        display[singledigitindex] = chr(charnum)
```

The first index value is the index into the list of display. The second index is part of the instance of the display object from class Seg14x8.  How could they be combined?

Comment: This is a _list_, not an [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array): `displayset = []`

Comment: I am able to create a structure where I reference the display as `display0[0] = '0'`  My goal is to create a structure (list or array) of objects that can be referenced as `display[0][0] = '0'`  What is the syntax to use in the class definition?  From the perspective of the objects, it is a one dimensional list.  When considering that each object can be addressed by digit, then it looks more like an array.

Comment: See edit of original question - I have a list of instances, but I want the addressing to include indexes of the instance objects. Is that possible?

Comment: `display[singledigitindex] =  x` would *overwrite* that index, not update any information stored by an object at that location, so not sure that's what you want